# Visual Studio вылетает при перетаскивании (компоновке) окон кода

Tags: visual-studio-2017

Проблема возникла относительно недавно. В Visual Studio я люблю работать с двумя файлами/группами файлов одновременно, поэтому компоную окна кода перетаскиванием их на иконку с необходимой компоновкой (по правой стороне, снизу, т.п.). Но теперь, как только я это делаю, студия полностью зависает и через небольшое время вылетает. Это также происходит и при перетаскивании встроенных в Visual Studio окон вроде "Обозревателя решений" и т.п. Если же я не компоную окна, а просто перетаскиваю и оставляю висеть в произвольном месте в качестве нового отдельного окна, то все работает нормально.

Answer (score 1):

Столкнулся с такой же проблемой. У меня все починилось установкой обновления. У тебя вверху справа есть иконка флага "Notifications", нажми на него, у тебя появится новое окно, в нем будут обновления для всех компонентов, в том числе для плагинов. Тебе нужно обновить саму студию.